# Next JS PWA not showing the offline page when the user goes offline for the first time

Tags: next.js

I'm using [next-pwa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa) library and following this [example](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/tree/master/examples/offline-fallback).

So what's happening here is that I open my website everything gets loaded and then I turn off my wifi/ goes offline then I click on any other link

**Expected Result:**

It should show me my offline page.

**Actual Result:**

It shows me an error

[image]

**Strange thing:**

Then I reload my page again and it starts showing me my offline page.

[image]

### My next.config.js

```js
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
  dest: "public",
  swSrc: "service-worker.js",
});

const nextConfig = withPWA({
  images: {
    domains: [],
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  optimizeFonts: false,
});
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

### My service-worker.js

```js
import { clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";
import { matchPrecache, precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute, setCatchHandler } from "workbox-routing";
import { NetworkFirst, CacheFirst } from "workbox-strategies";
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from "workbox-cacheable-response";
import { ExpirationPlugin } from "workbox-expiration";

self.skipWaiting(); // DONT WAIT FOR USER TO CLOSE ALL TAB
clientsClaim(); //  take control ASAP

const WB_MANIFEST = self.__WB_MANIFEST;
// Precache fallback route and image
WB_MANIFEST.push({
  url: "/fallback",
  revision: "1234567890",
});
precacheAndRoute(WB_MANIFEST);

// cache for image
registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === "image",
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: "images",
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200],
      }),
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 60,
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

registerRoute(
  /.*/i,
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: "others",
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 32,
        maxAgeSeconds: 86400,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

// This "catch" handler is triggered when any of the other routes fail to
// generate a response.
setCatchHandler(({ event }) => {
  switch (event.request.destination) {
    case "document":
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache("/fallback");

      break;
    case "image":
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache("/static/images/fallback.png");

    case "font":
    // If using precached URLs:
    // return matchPrecache(FALLBACK_FONT_URL);
    //return caches.match('/static/fonts/fallback.otf')
    //break
    default:
      // If we don't have a fallback, just return an error response.
      return matchPrecache("/fallback");
  }
});
```

**My manifest.json:**

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/web-manifest-combined.json",
  "name": "Title",
  "short_name": "Title",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "description": "SOME TEST",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/touch/manifestIcon48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/touch/manifestIcon72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/touch/manifestIcon96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/touch/manifestIcon96.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/touch/manifestIcon48.png",
      "sizes": "168x168",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/touch/manifestIcon192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

### My Fallback Page:

```js
import React from "react";
const Fallback = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen w-screen items-center justify-center ">
      <div className="flex w-screen justify-center items-center  ">
        <img src="/fallback.png" className="h-[80px] w-[80px]" />
      </div>
      <div className="items-center justify-center flex font-raleway font-[700] text-[35px] mt-2">
        No Internet
      </div>

      <div className="items-center justify-center text-center mx-10 flex font-raleway text-[20px] mt-5 leading-8">
        <p>
          Looks like you are not connected to the network. Check your setting
          and try again.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Fallback;
```

### What I have tried

1. Make sure my service work is active and working[image]
2. Fall back page and fallback image is precached properly [image]

Can anyone please help me I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, it seems like the issue is occurring when you go offline and then click on any other link on your website. Instead of showing the expected offline page, it shows an error, and only upon reloading the page, it starts showing the offline page.

One possible reason for this behavior could be due to the caching mechanism used in your service worker. The NetworkFirst strategy used for caching might be preventing the fallback page from being served when the network is offline.

To resolve this issue, you can try modifying your service worker to use the CacheFirst strategy for serving the fallback page when the network is offline. Here's an example of how you can modify your service worker to use the CacheFirst strategy:

```js
setCatchHandler(({ event }) => {
  switch (event.request.destination) {
    case "document":
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache("/fallback");

    case "image":
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache("/static/images/fallback.png");

    case "font":
      // If using precached URLs:
      // return matchPrecache(FALLBACK_FONT_URL);
      //return caches.match('/static/fonts/fallback.otf')
      //break

    default:
      // If we don't have a fallback in the cache, return an error response.
      return new Response("Service Unavailable", {
        status: 503,
        statusText: "Service Unavailable",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        },
      });
  }
});

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === "document",
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: "pages",
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [200],
      }),
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 60,
        maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```

In this modified service worker code, the CacheFirst strategy is used for serving the fallback page when the network is offline. Additionally, a CacheableResponsePlugin is used to cache the responses with a status code of 200, and an ExpirationPlugin is used to specify the maximum age and number of entries for cached responses.

With these modifications, your service worker should be able to serve the fallback page when the network is offline without requiring a page reload.

Comment: I have 2 question. First now I'm using CacheFirst so the website will alwasy going to show outdated data until cache expire right ?. I dont want that I want to always load the latest data

Comment: "Secondly, I'm confused as to why using NetworkFirst strategy did not work, even though I set up a setCatchHandler. If the request was failing, shouldn't it have shown the fallback page?"